# Azure Kubernetes Service Node Pool How to specify OS disk type?

Tags: azure-aks

Is it possible to specify disk type for OS disk when creating a node pool in AKS cluster? By default, I see the disk type used is Premium LRS. I know it is possible to control OS Disk Size via `--node-osdisk-size` when creating a new node pool, but I don't see an ability to specify something like `--node-osdisk-type`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to select the disk type when creating a Node Pool in AKS. If the VM support premium disks, it will use premium disk. It is one of the most upvote [feature request for AKS](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/914020-azure-kubernetes-service-aks/suggestions/35056588-allow-selecting-disk-type-when-creating-aks-cluste)

Answer (score 3):

There is (now) a `--os-disk-type` parameter, see

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-configuration#use-ephemeral-os-on-new-clusters

Comment: so this flag we can set '--node-osdisk-type Ephemeral' but how to we pick StandardSSD vs PremiumSSD?